# ExtJS: How to override custom minimize behavior of Ext.window.Window?

Tags: extjs, position, window, overriding, minimize

There is a [`minimizable`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/classic/Ext.window.Window.html#cfg-minimizable) boolean config which fires [`minimize`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/classic/Ext.window.Window.html#event-minimize) event.

The question is, how can I override and define a new position on `DOM` for this event? My aim is minimize the window to `footer` `panel` of application.

Below stated `minimize` function of [Ext.window.Window](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/classic/Ext.window.Window.html);

```
minimize: function () {
    this.fireEvent('minimize', this);
    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this like below:-

```
"minimize": function (window, opts) {
    window.collapse();
    window.setWidth(150);
    window.alignTo(Ext.getBody(), 'bl-bl')
}
```

[**Working fiddle**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1tlr&view/editor)

**Note:** You can read more about `alignTo` options [**here**](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.Component.html#method-alignTo).

Comment: is that possible to `alignTo` to a specific class such as `'Ext.tab.Panel'`. I've class; `Ext.define('MyApp.MainPanel', { extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel', alias: 'widget.mainpanel',` and setted `minimize` method as `window.alignTo(Ext.getBody(), 'mainpanel');` but of course return error: `Uncaught Error: Attempted to align an element with an invalid position: "tl-mainpanel"`

Comment: Please read [alignTo](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.Component.html#method-alignTo) method in docs properly and then you can try it.

Comment: I'm looking 'set auto offset' during minimize multiple window but couldn't achieve for any good sample/suggestion. Could you please share any idea for this aim? My aim; I'll have several windows and each of them can be minimized but the thing with this implementation; all of minimized windows comes over and over and user can not know how many windows has been minimized. Therefore I thought why doesn't set a auto offset! If any window minimized already then minimize new one at right side of it. But as I told couldn't find any good sample. Any idea for this approach?

Answer (score -1):

another minimize and restore window [more tuned variant](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3kc1).
working for all windows at once just set minimizable to true.

```
 Ext.override(Ext.window.Window, {
    isMinimizeInPlace: false,// collapse without moving
    minimizePosition: 'bl-bl', //bottom-left of this window and bottom-left of the alingTo component
    minimizePositionOffset: [5, -5],// offset at moved position while isMinimizeInPlace=false
    minimizeTitleWidth: 150, //window width when collapsed. set to 0 if need do not change width
    _isMinimized: false,
    getTool: function (type) {
        let tools = this.down('header').items.items;
        return tools.find(c => c.type === type);
    },
    minimize: function (evt, toolEl, owner, tool) {
        if (!this.minimizable) return false;
        if (this._isMinimized) {
            this.expand('', false);
            this.setWidth(this.winWidth);
            if (!this.isMinimizeInPlace) {
                this.alignTo(Ext.getBody(), 'tl-tl', this.winPosition);
            }
            this._isMinimized = false;
            let minimizeTool = this.getTool('minimize');
            let restoreTool = this.getTool('restore');
            restoreTool.hide();
            minimizeTool.show();
        } else {
            //console.log(this, tool)
            this.collapse();
            this.winWidth = this.getWidth();
            this.winPosition = this.getOffsetsTo(Ext.getBody());
            if (this.minimizeTitleWidth){
                this.setWidth(this.minimizeTitleWidth);
            }
            let minimizeTool = this.getTool('minimize');
            let restoreTool = this.getTool('restore');
            restoreTool.show();
            minimizeTool.hide();
            this._isMinimized = true;
            if (!this.isMinimizeInPlace) {
                this.alignTo(Ext.getBody(), this.minimizePosition, this.minimizePositionOffset);
            }
        }
    },

    tools: [{
        type: 'restore',
        hidden: true,
        handler: function (evt, toolEl, owner, tool) {
            owner.up('window').minimize(...arguments);
        }
    }]
})
```